# how to place a button within a table in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, button, jtable

In the properties windows ,  we come across buttons in a table cell < as in font property's row , a button can be clicked on to set font properties > . Is there a way to insert a button in a Jtable 's second column < which i've created using netbeans >..  how to do that , if it is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) shows one approach.

Answer (score 1):

Found an [example](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=680674) pretty easily by searching for "JButton in JTable" on Google.